# sed replacement for a negative number

Tags: regex, linux, sed

hi I have a file containing numbers like

```
-640.68739330746
```

which I need to be changed to

```
(-  640.68739330746 )
```

I tried using this code

```
sed 's/(-[0-9]\d*(\.\d+))/\(\(-\s\s[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)\s\))\1\*\2//g'
```

but I am getting errors

Comment: `sed` doesn't support `\d` for one thing and there's an extra `/` at the end

Answer (score 3):

Use `[0-9]` character class to match digits and rely on regex captured groups `(...)`:

```
sed -E 's/-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/(- \1 )/g' file
```

---

Sample test:

```
$ cat s1
-640.68739330746 -1.3 sdfsdf
-2.3333
$ sed -E 's/-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/( & )/g' s1
(- 640.68739330746 ) (- 1.3 ) sdfsdf
(- 2.3333 )
```

Comment: I think you meant `(- \1 )` as OP has space between `-` and number in expected output

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, in case you are ok with `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i<0){$i="( "$i" )"}}} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

Let's say following is the Input_file(test data only):

```
cat Input_file
-640.68739330746 efuiweiuwv wnwvn 1213133 -0.9 -4 wvnwnvrnvn
```

When we run following code get following output then.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i<0){$i="( "$i" )"}}} 1' Input_file
( -640.68739330746 ) efuiweiuwv wnwvn 1213133 ( -0.9 ) ( -4 ) wvnwnvrnvn
```